# How can i fix the display data

Tags: magento2

It's show the same row data
but database it not duplicate
where should code i fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
   <!-- Add Column from your db -->
<columns name="grid_records_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </column>
   <column name="customer_email">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer E-mail</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>
   <column name="customer_name">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>
   <column name="review">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Review</item>
        </item>
       </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
               <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated At</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
    </column>
   <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
   <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Customer\Review\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
               <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

i create table field is
id (primary) ,customer_email,customer_name,review,created_at,updated_at

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, maybe it'll help

Change this code

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
    </item>
</argument>
```

to this

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: it's work thank you!.